# Solidity: Disable Buying and Selling if CurrentPrice is below LastTransactionPrice?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Is it possible in Solidity to compare
LastTransactionPrice with CurrentAsk & CurrentBid?

then
Disable Buying/Selling if the price (Ask/Bid) is below LastTransactionPrice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You create 3 state variables for CurrentAsk, CurrentBid and LastTransactionPrice:

```
uint256 CurrentAsk private;
uint256 CurrentBid private;
uint256 LastTransactionPrice private;
```

then write to setters to mutate those two state variables:

```
// askPrice gets set by the seller
function setCurrentAsk(uint256 askPrice) public {
  CurrentAsk=askPrice
}

// bidPrice gets set by the buyer
function setCurrentBid(uint256 bidPrice) public {
  CurrentBid=bidPrice
}
```

You can write a require statement to add buying/selling function but in this way, people still can call `setCurrentAsk` and `setCurrentBid` functions and pay gas fees. To be more efficient, you add require statements to both functions.

```
function setCurrentAsk(uint256 askPrice) public {
      require(askPrice>LastTransactionPrice,"ask higher amount")
      CurrentAsk=askPrice
    }


function setCurrentBid(uint256 bidPrice) public {
      require(bidPrice > LastTransactionPrice, "ask higher amount")
      CurrentBid=bidPrice
    }
```

`require` statement will check the current condition and if does not return `true`, it will revert the function execution and solidity will show the error that you defined: "ask higher amount"

Comment: How do you get the LastTransactionPrice? Thank you!

Comment: @johnnybegoode you initalize it first and then in "buying/selling" function when you make sell, you update LastTransactionPrice

Comment: Would you need to handle the first-ever transaction? Thank you!

Comment: How would you initialize it? Thank you!